# Track played second in mplayer

Tags: mplayer, jquery

I am using mplayer.js. I want to check no of second my track is played. I have used method ***gettime***() but it gives me 00:00.

Comment: Could you give more context?

Comment: Ex. My track is of 5 min. I play song for 3 min and switch to the next song at that time I want to check how much my my first track is played / stream